# How to write an ordered list which contains nested unordered lists (GitHub markdown)

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

From the docs here:
(https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/),
you can create a nested list by indenting one or more list items below another item.

---

[image]

But I'm trying to create an ordered list with nested *unordered* lists.

---

I tried this code:

```
1. Ordered One
  * Unordered First
  * Unordered Second
  * Unordered Third
1. Ordered Second
  * Unordered One
  * Unordered Two
  * Unordered Three
```

---

and what I get is this:

[image]

---

How can I write this so `Ordered Second` automatically gets number `2.` and the unordered nested lists are properly indented?

Thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is because your top-level list numbers in your example begin with a space in front.  Eliminate that space and use three spaces for the sub-level indentation.

It isn't necessary to eliminate the space as it seems the key in GitHub's markdown is that there are three spaces differentiating the levels.  So if you started with one space in front, the next level would have to have four spaces from the start of the line.

```
1. Ordered One
   * Unordered First
   * Unordered Second
   * Unordered Third
1. Ordered Second
   * Unordered One
   * Unordered Two
   * Unordered Three
```

1. Ordered One

   - Unordered First
   - Unordered Second
   - Unordered Third
2. Ordered Second

   - Unordered One
   - Unordered Two
   - Unordered Three

Comment: I don't have a space in front of the top-level numbers `1.`, but using three spaces for the sub-level did the trick. I was indenting using just two spaces. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that with a little more experimentation as well.  The key is the three spaces.

Comment: In this situation, yes you would need three spaces, but the actual rule is more complicated than that. In other situations you would need more or less spaces. For an explanation of why see [Markdown enumerated list with indices over 99 changes nested list formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49302511/866026). As a reminder, GitHub uses the CommonMark spec.

Comment: In short the real answer is about columns. The opening character of a nested list item must line up in the same column as the first character of the content (which follows both the list marker and the space after it) of the parent item.